# Toggle button inside linear layout not showing on off text

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I have toggle buttons inside linear layout and on click they do not show the ontext and offtext.I also have listener for all toggle buttons and inside onclick function i tried to set the ontext but it didn't work.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.example.sharmila.eeeeeee.tryfragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/try_fragment" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/wholenote"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@drawable/a"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="S"
        android:textSize="700dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/halfnote"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@drawable/b"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="S"
        android:textSize="700dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/quarternote"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="@drawable/c"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="S"
        android:textSize="700dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/eightnote"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:background="@drawable/d"
        android:textOn="S"
        android:textSize="700dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textOff=""/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/sixteennote"
        android:textOn="S"
        android:textSize="700dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textOff=""
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:background="@drawable/e"
        />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textOn="S"
        android:textSize="700dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:id="@+id/thirtytwonote"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:background="@drawable/g"
       />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textOn="S"
        android:textSize="700dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:id="@+id/sixyfournote"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:background="@drawable/f"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
     <TableRow android:id="@+id/Linearlayout2"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:weightSum="1">
    <View
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.34" />
      <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:src="@drawable/pause" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.18" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:src="@drawable/play" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.18" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:src="@drawable/stop"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3"/>

</TableRow>


<GridLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Linearlayout2"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Prev"
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="19" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="save"
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Finish"
        android:id="@+id/finish"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="21" />

</GridLayout>
```

Activity code:

```
private static ToggleButton wholenote;
private static ToggleButton halfnote;
private static ToggleButton quarternote;
private static ToggleButton eighthnote;
private static ToggleButton sixteenthnote;
private static ToggleButton thirtytwonote;
private static ToggleButton sixtyfourthnote;
private static String selected = "01";

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    wholenote = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.wholenote);
    wholenote.setOnClickListener(this);
    halfnote = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.halfnote);
    halfnote.setOnClickListener(this);
    quarternote = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.quarternote);
    quarternote.setOnClickListener(this);
    eighthnote = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.eightnote);
    eighthnote.setOnClickListener(this);
    sixteenthnote = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.sixteennote);
    sixteenthnote.setOnClickListener(this);
    thirtytwonote = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.thirtytwonote);
    thirtytwonote.setOnClickListener(this);
    sixtyfourthnote = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.sixyfournote);
    sixtyfourthnote.setOnClickListener(this);

   }
 public void onClick(View view) {
      switch (view.getId()) {
     case R.id.wholenote:
            wholenote.setTextOn("S");
            break;
        case R.id.halfnote:
            halfnote.setTextOn("S");
            break;
        case R.id.quarternote:
            quarternote.setTextOn("S");
            break;
        case R.id.eightnote:
            eightnote.setTextOn("S");
            break;
        case R.id.sixteennote:
            sixteennote.setTextOn("S");
            break;
        case R.id.thirtytwonote:
            thirtytwonote.setTextOn("S");
            break;
        case R.id.sixyfournote:
            sixtyfournote.setTextOn("S");
            break;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:textSize="700dp"
```

It's not showing on off text,it is because you text size is too large to show it on screen.
Set all togglebuttons textSize 10dp.

```
android:textSize="10dp"
```

Comment: such a silly mistake i have done. Thank you for pointing out :) it worked

Comment: @lionscribe What should I do?

Comment: Click on the check next to their answer, so it turns green.

Comment: @lionscribe sorry,I don't understand what you mean.Sad :(